# Spring WS and MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, tomcat7, httpconnection

I have a web service on Spring WS 2.1.0. Web service runs on Tomcat 7 and implements an endpoint with one transactional method that read data from database and generate different reports. Tomcat 7 runs behind Apache Server via JServ protocol.

During stress test via Apache JMeter I came to conclusion that simultaneous requests are handled serially. At first I tried to tune database connection pool (commons-dbcp and later tomcat-jdbc) but result was the same. Endpoint method only reads data, so there are no read-after-write or write-after-read dependencies and transactions could by handled in parallel. Thus the problem is in HTTP connections handling.

After some searching (and googling, of course) I found out that Spring WS comes with the default connection manager(SimpleHttpConnectionManager) which is single threaded. The good practise is to replace SimpleHttpConnectionManager with MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager. I found sample code that looks like this:

```
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager>
            <property name="maxConnectionsPerHost" value="20"/>
            <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="100"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But this example isn't rather clear to me because I don't understand how Spring uses HttpClient (refers to ID or autowiring it).  So how can I use MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager with Spring in my case? Where should I inject configured instance of this class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the usage of `HttpClient`. It's only used in Spring WS **client** module to initiate HTTP connections, see [*6.2.1.1.1. HTTP transports*](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html):

> There are two implementations of the `WebServiceMessageSender` interface for sending messages via HTTP. [...] The alternative is the `CommonsHttpMessageSender`, which uses the Jakarta Commons HttpClient.

`HttpClient` is not needed at all when Spring WS is used on the server side. In that case it's the servlet container that provides HTTP (server) abstraction. Check out your Tomcat configuration, maybe the thread pool is too small and some requests are queued? `HttpClient` has absolutely nothing to do here. I'm sorry, but you'll have to look for a problem somewhere else.

---

Just to keep the answer complete, when you use Spring WS to access SOAP services on other computer, the following settings of `HttpClient` apply:

- `maxConnectionsPerHost` - how many concurrent connections `HttpClient` is allowed to keep to the same host (see: `Keep-Alive` header)? Most browsers limit the number of concurrent connections to the same host to 2/4/8. `HttpClient` follows that behaviour, so in principle you cannot have more then 2/4/8 (whatever you set here) concurrent connections to the same host.
- `maxTotalConnections` - like above, but total to all hosts. If you are connecting to hundreds of different web services on different servers, this is the total number of open connections `HttpClient` can keep

Comment: Thanks for helpful reply. I was really confused with trying to use MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager on the server side. My assumptions concerning handing HTTP requests were wrong because after several hours of debugging different parts of code I found out that the problem was in some 3rd party libraries. They read data from remote secured storage without any caching that had led to sequential request handling